# Breakpoints Skipped in Xdebug with Eclipse for New Project

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, xdebug

XDebug was working great for my previous project, but when I created a new project, it breaks at the first line but skips all break points thereafter. When I first set up Xdebug, I had a similar problem (but it did not even break at the first line and gets stuck on "Launching..."), it was solved when I changed xdebug.remote_port to 9001 in my php.ini. Right now I have

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

in my php.ini. I am using this to develop a custom Drupal module, and I have the Drupal extensions (*.module, *.install etc) listed under the PHP content type in my Eclipse settings. When I go back and try debugging my old project, all breakpoints still work. I tried closing the old project, and restarting Eclipse before debugging the new one. Breakpoints in the new project are still skipped.

Am I forgetting some project setup step? I just went to New>>PHP Project, then set up an SVN repository and started working.

I am using Eclipse Helios, with PDT SDK Feature 2.2.1.

Answer (score 4):

i'm having a similar issue with vista+netbeans+wamp+chrome+drupal.
if i set a breakpoint in the function line statement, xdebug is able to catch the breakpoint. if i put the breakpoint inside a function, xdebug skips the breakpoint.